# MIPS programming convention, using ADD for everything

Tags: mips, conventions

I have seen a lot of people using ADD for everything instead of using specific keywords.

```
add $t0, $zero, $t1  ---> move $t0, $t1
add $t0, $zero, $zero  ---> li $t0, 0
addi $t0, $t0, -1   ---> subi $t0, $t0, 1
```

Why? I'd totally use the "move", or "li", etc rather than using all ADD all the time. Is this a convention? If so, can somebody explain using arguments why it's better to use Add in this manner?

Comment: `add $t0, $t0, $t1` is not equivalent to `move $t0, $t1`

Comment: [I fixed it] Yes, I meant something like add $t0, $zero, $t1. Just a little mistake

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116018/mips-instruction-set-move-vs-add-addi-0-for-storing-values
Fascinating that there is an assembly language without a move instruction.

Comment: `move`, `li`, and `subi`, IIRC, are pseudo-instructions (i.e. no corresponding opcode) which gets mapped to the version on the left (or something equivalent) when translated to machine code.

Comment: @Mike that's because of the first design principle of MIPS: [*Simplicity favors regularity*](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=1lD9LZRcIZ8C&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=MIPS+%22simplicity+favors+regularity%22&source=bl&ots=o7x1paJbFz&sig=noljI0-1ZPqDx8JlvzyuqEE424g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h5iGVN7NLNfmuQTmwYDYBg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=MIPS%20%22simplicity%20favors%20regularity%22&f=false). You don't need a move when you can achieve that with another simple instruction. And many other RISC architecture follow that too

Comment: Ah, yes. The R in RISC. I'm more familiar with ARM (and the Archimedes ARM1 from '90) which does. Thanks for the link, it is restricted but I'll search for another source. Presumably, that's the Pipelining in MIPS - are all opcode-operand pairs the same size?