# How to set one register to the value stored in another register in the optimal way in MIPS?

Tags: mips, mips32, mars-simulator

Let's say we want to set $a0 = $s3
I know there are:

- move $a0, $s3
- or $a0, $zero, $s3

Which one is better practice or more optimal? Why?
Is there another better way?

Comment: I have no experience with MIPS, but x86. I would say, that using `move` is at least more  readable.

Comment: What is your criteria for optimal?  `move` is readable, but a pseudo instruction that the hardware doesn't have so is translated into something like the `addu` by the assembler; `or` is less readable but a real instruction; both result in the same operation, they are both the same size, and the same speed.

Comment: i thought maybe or would be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction `or $a0, $zero, $s3` is equivalent to `addi $a0, $s3, 0`, so please read this thread: [MIPS instruction set move vs add/addi 0 for storing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116018/mips-instruction-set-move-vs-add-addi-0-for-storing-values)